# Catching errors on boost::ptime stream

Tags: c++, boost

I have a function which returns a formatted date/time string. The actual date and time is constant; it is the formatting of the resultant string that I am after.

```
std::string example_datetime(const std::string &boostspec)
{
    std::ostringstream os;
    os.imbue(std::locale(std::locale::classic(), new boost::posix_time::time_facet(boostspec.c_str())));
    os << boost::posix_time::time_from_string("2014-02-13 08:30:00.000");
    return os.fail() ? "invalid specifier" : os.str();
};
```

and I'll use the function like this:

```
std::string str(example_datetime("%a %b %d, %Y, %H:%M:%S"));
```

The problem I am having occurs when I pass an invalid `boostspec` string. The 3<sup>rd</sup> line within the function crashes, before it gets to the `os.fail()` check. I have tried catching all the exceptions I can think of, but can't seem to find anything that works. Checking the validity of the `boostspec` specifier string is a key purpose of this function.

*edit: I’m using boost 1.63 and VS2012.
It reliably crashes for me when boostspec = “%a % “ — note the spaces*

Comment: Do you have an example of a bootspec that makes it crash? I cannot reproduce it. (If it raises an exception, that's not crashing and if it crashes, that is a bug by definition)

Comment: @sehe Yes, thanks! Try something like “%a % %”. Note the spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

It looks like there is a bug in MSVC's standard library implementation. Boost delegates some work to [`std::time_put<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/time_put) by default:

**<kbd>[Live On http://rextester.com/TMXPG58348](http://rextester.com/TMXPG58348)</kbd>**

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    try {
    // std::locale::global(std::locale("de_DE.utf8"));
    std::time_t t = std::time(NULL);
    std::tm tm = *std::localtime(&t);

    std::string const fmt = "%a % ";
    std::use_facet<std::time_put<char> >(std::cout.getloc())
        .put({ std::cout }, std::cout, ' ', &tm, fmt.data(), fmt.data() + fmt.size());
    } catch(...) {
        std::cerr << "An exception was raised\n";
    }
}
```

Which results in

[image]

It is possible your problem lies elsewhere:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e5963fd92bdfc332)**

```
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_io.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

std::string example_datetime(const std::string &boostspec)
{
    std::ostringstream os;
    os.imbue(std::locale(std::locale::classic(), new boost::posix_time::time_facet(boostspec.c_str())));
    os << boost::posix_time::time_from_string("2014-02-13 08:30:00.000");
    return os.fail() ? "invalid specifier" : os.str();
}

int main() {
    std::cout << example_datetime("%a % %") << std::endl;
    std::cout << example_datetime("“%a % %”") << std::endl;
}
```

Prints

```
Thu % 
“Thu % %”
```

Just fine.

Comment: I'm going to check with some older boost versions, meanwhile the changelog might mention a related bug fixed

Comment: I don’t think my boost is very old. I’m certain the problem isn’t in other parts of my own code. That would only leave a bug in VS 2012 - which wouldn’t surprise me. It’s really late here; tomorrow I’ll try it on my Linux server. Thanks so much for the feedback!

Comment: How can you be sure the problem isn't elsewhere? Does this fail in isolation on VS2012? (PS Not a problem with boost 1.54: https://wandbox.org/permlink/z2nvvnnNlbVKSQm5)

Comment: I haven’t tried. But it’s a brutally simple segment.

Comment: I couldn't help but fire the computer up and try. It does crash in isolation on VS2012. I'm using boost 1.63.0.

Comment: Ok, here's the difference. It fails on "%a % ", where there is a space at the end.

Comment: 1. that's funny because I literally copy/pasted your reproducer case 2. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/71ddc9636bd3bf7a - Maybe you can spot the library bug in the debugger?

Comment: I did dig through it. But it goes pretty deep. It ends up crashing at an: assign(_Right, 0, npos) -- within .../VC/include/xstring, where npos is equal to max unsigned int (ie 4294967295) for some reason. I really think this is a VC2012 bug - which would suck, because I wouldn't have a fix.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158588/discussion-between-sehe-and-blair-fonville).